# How can I hide/display add to cart button from Shopify product pages using Shopify app in Laravel or Node?

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api

I am writing an app and I want to make a switch button to hide/display 'Add to Cart' button by using this app. How can I write code and implement this in Liquid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP (Laravel) as the backend for your Shopify App you could use the "phpclassic/php-shopify" library and call the "ScriptTag" method to load an external Javascript file into a store's front-end.  The JavaScript file would have to manipulate the DOM to hide/display the Add to Cart button.

Code to hide any add-to-cart buttons might look like:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button.add-to-cart')).map(el=>el.style.display='none');
```

If you wanted to conditionally hide buttons for specific products, then the JavaScript file would need to talk to your App back-end to obtain that information.

Note that this does not involve Liquid at all. Liquid is the theme template laguage Shopify uses. Programmatically modifying the theme's liquid files is a more difficult approach and liquid files you've added via an App get left behind if your App is uninstalled.